Vapor barrier for sil plate and fire block
I'm about to start working on my finishing my basement; but every time I'm about to start I realize a new question.
From what I understand from discussing with the local building department I will need a fireblock between the floors, they seem to be fine with using Mineral wool in the cavity to slow any spread of fire. (not sure if it matters, my exterior basement walls are cinderblocks and I'm planning to put foam board on the wall and then fill the 2x4 wall with rockwool mineral wool)
Currently in my basement around the inside of the sil plate there is fiberglass insulation with backing acting as a vapor barrier.
So the question is quite simply, is the vapor barrier needed on the sil plate? Or is it enough to fill with Mineral Wool? At least at some point I did read something about vapor barriers being optional when using mineral wool (Sounds wrong to me, but...)
Or what are the other options to incorporate vapor barrier with the fireblock?
This is in NE Ohio
